# Stop the Running Thread in Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am using the thread for login on Server and I want to stop the Thread as the user press back button, I am using stop() and destroy() method and these methods crashing my application, I think these Methods are depreciated that why I am facing this problem. Please Give me the way to stop thread without using stop() and destroy().

Comment: Start an IntentService instead of a Thread. Or use Thread.setDaemon(true)

Comment: @TheLostMind I have tried Thread.setDaemon(true), but this is also crashing the application. And I dont want to use IntentService,just Thread.  Thanks For your help

Comment: Don't use thread or AsyncTask, use Volley, this has methods to cancel your request at any stage.

Comment: @Puneet, What about the "Volley" , could pls elaborate about this ?

Comment: Volley is a Google project, they are using this in Google base application development, this is 10 times faster than AsyncTask, I had use this for my application, you can learn more about this here http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Thread.stop()` is deprecated since java 1.1 (~17 years ago...). Java of this method explains the reasons in details. This means that you should never call this method. It is still there for backwards compatibility with code written when I was young.

But what to do if you want to "cancel" the operation done in thread? The answer is that you (developer) should care about this yourself. How? It depends on your application. If for example your thread opens i/o stream you can close the stream. If your thread performs series of operations in loop you should check special flag that indicates that thread should exit and update this flag according to needs of your application (in your case when user presses "back" button.

If you still have problem please try to give more details what does your thread do and you will probably get concrete recommendations how to stop it.

Comment: As a developer, I know the such methods as you have mentioned using Flag etc. but I am performing such operation which is not only using the loops etc. I would like let you know that My thread is posting  the request to server for Login and it takes some time for the response and I want to stop the thread in between so that there should be no communication between my application and server.
Now. I am using the " threadObject.interrupt();  threadobject = null " using this way I have solved the problem, Please let me know this way is right or Not , Thanks for Your support

Comment: OK, this I mentioned this case in my explanation too. You can close your input stream and it will throw exception on read. Other way is to separate your login operation to 2: short "send login command", then "get login status." Both operations returns immideately. Second operation returns status: `OK`, `FAIL`, `TRY_LATER`.

Comment: Now I am using "threadObject.interrupt(); threadobject = null" and Its working fine, Just let me know is This good way or not. Thanks AlexR

Comment: Yes, this is fine. I am sorry, that I forgot to write you about this way. I kept it in mind when typing but forgot to write. This however is not the "universal" solution. It is good if your thread is blocked on `wait()`, `sleep()` or IO operations that respect interrupts. Please note however that this does not kill the process at server side. It just causes client to "disconnect" from server IO stream.

Comment: yes it does not kill the process at server, But works fine for the client side.  Really thanks Guy for you help

Answer (score 0):

For background thread in android try to use service. 
I mean you  start a service and put a thread in that service.
If you want to stop that service then pressed back button try "Bound" Service. You will get basic idea here.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Answer (score 0):

Only use a thread if you want to do work repeatedly for a long time. I have never needed to start a thread.

You should look at using an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

> AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

It works by using a Thread from the ThreadPool. AsyncTask's are easy to stop, have a method to override for background tasks and one to override for post task work which is suitable for updating the UI (as long as the task was started by the UI thread).

Comment: Really Nice to listen. As I have performed the various operations using Thread class, so it would be difficult to handle all those operations so thats why I want to know solution of my problem. Thanks Westom